# Component Fields available in GUI Extension with fieldBuilder

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I would like to get all the Component fields in the Component View from a GUI Extension.  I am following the excellent code sampels provided here:  [GUI extension to hide field in 2011 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/gui-extension-to-hide-field-in-2011-sp1)

My problem is that the fieldBuilder.properties collection does not contain an input property, and only contains 11 total properties at my breakpoint in the GUI Extension.  However, when I use the same javascript code in the Chrome console I do get input and also I have a total of 24 properties.

How can I change the EventHandler or my config to get it at a later moment in the window loading?  Config and Javascript posted below:

Readonly.js

```
//If you only want your code to affect certain screens/views, you should listen to Anguilla events like this:
$evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStartedReadonly);

// This callback is called when any view has finished loading
function onDisplayStartedReadonly() {
    console.log('View=' + $display.getView().getId());

    $evt.removeEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStartedReadonly);

    if ($display.getView().getId() == "ComponentView") {
        debugger;
        var fieldBuilder = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder;

        fieldsContainer = fieldBuilder.properties.input;
        fieldsNode = fieldsContainer.getElement();
        control = null;

        $j(fieldsNode).children().each(function (index, elm) {
            var cntrl = $j('div.input', elm)[0].control;
            console.log('fieldname=' + cntrl.getFieldName());
        });
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
               xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters />
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="Readonly.CommandSet" merge="always">
        <cfg:fileset>
            <cfg:file type="script" id="jQuery16Readonly">/Readonly/jquery-1.6.4.js</cfg:file>
            <cfg:file type="script" id="readonlyJs">/Readonly/Readonly.js</cfg:file>
        </cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
        </cfg:dependencies>

      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles />
  <extensions>
    <ext:dataextenders />
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:editurls />
        <ext:listdefinitions />
        <ext:taskbars />
        <ext:commands />
        <ext:commandextensions>
          <ext:commands>
          </ext:commands>
          <ext:dependencies>
            <cfg:dependency>Readonly.CommandSet</cfg:dependency>
          </ext:dependencies>
        </ext:commandextensions>
        <ext:contextmenus />
        <ext:lists />
        <ext:tabpages />
        <ext:toolbars />
        <ext:ribbontoolbars />
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
  </extensions>
  <commands>
    <cfg:commandset/>
  </commands>
  <contextmenus />
  <localization />
  <settings>
    <defaultpage />
    <editurls />
    <listdefinitions />
    <itemicons />
    <theme>
      <path />
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration>
    </customconfiguration>
  </settings>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run your extension code when the thread gets executed. To do so, try following

```
function onDisplayStartedReadonly() 
{
    $evt.removeEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStartedReadonly);

    function onDisplayStartedReadonly$_collectProperties()
    {
        if ($display.getView().getId() == "ComponentView") 
        {
            debugger;
            var fieldBuilder = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder;

            fieldsContainer = fieldBuilder.properties.input;
            fieldsNode = fieldsContainer.getElement();
            control = null;

            $j(fieldsNode).children().each(function (index, elm) {
                var cntrl = $j('div.input', elm)[0].control;
                console.log('fieldname=' + cntrl.getFieldName());
            });
        }
    }

    setTimeout(onDisplayStartedReadonly$_collectProperties, 0);
}
```

---

and plan "B", is to listen on on fieldbuilder "load" event

```
if ($display)
{
    (function()
    {
        $evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", Extension$onDisplayStartedReadonly);

        function Extension$onDisplayStartedReadonly()
        {
            $evt.removeEventHandler($display, "start", Extension$onDisplayStartedReadonly);

            var view = $display.getView();
            if (view && Tridion.OO.implementsInterface(view, "Tridion.Cme.Views.Component"))
            {
                var fieldBuilder = view.properties.controls.fieldBuilder;
                $evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "load", Extension$onDisplayStartedReadonly$_collectProperties);
            }
        };

        function Extension$onDisplayStartedReadonly$_collectProperties(event)
        {
            var fieldBuilder = event && event.source;
            if (fieldBuilder)
            {
                var fieldsContainer = fieldBuilder.properties.input;
                var fieldsNode = fieldsContainer.getElement();
                var control = null;

                $j(fieldsNode).children().each(function (index, elm)
                {
                    var cntrl = $j('div.input', elm)[0].control;
                    console.log('fieldname=' + cntrl.getFieldName());
                });
            }
        };
    })();
}
```

Comment: I have the same result:  fieldBuilder is available but fieldsContainer is 'undefined'.  I use the same code, but also have this addEventHandler at the top, $evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStartedReadonly);  Any ideas?

Comment: Well.. quick-trick didn`t help. The problem is that fuildBuilder is already uses setTimeout(.. , 0). What I was hoping is that it puts the execution after the fuildbuilded will do so.
As a plan "B", you can listen fielbuilder itself, when it gets loaded it will fire "load" event

Comment: How would I listen to the fieldBuilder?

Comment: Plan "B" is the winner.  :)  Thanks for the excellent detailed working solution.

Answer (score 7):

I think that a more elegant and efficient way to accomplish it is by extending a Resources Group, for instance you may want to just load your script when the Component View is loaded and not for every single request (Domain Model Script).

Here a sample:

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
               xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters />

    <cfg:extensiongroups>
      <cfg:extensiongroup name="Tridion.Extensions.ComponentView.Fields">
        <cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Component">
          <cfg:insertafter>Tridion.Extensions.ComponentView.FieldsGroup</cfg:insertafter>
        </cfg:extension>
      </cfg:extensiongroup>
    </cfg:extensiongroups>

    <cfg:groups>
        <cfg:group name="Tridion.Extensions.ComponentView.FieldsGroup">
            <cfg:fileset>
              <cfg:file type="script">/Extensions/Script/Fields.js</cfg:file>
            </cfg:fileset>
        </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>

    .....

    <resourceextensions>
      <resourceextension>Tridion.Extensions.ComponentView.Fields</resourceextension>
    </resourceextensions>

</Configuration>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What is the parent node for resourceextension?  Thanks for the nice tip!

Comment: It should be inside <settings>