# How to get Component metadata fields with fieldBuilder?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I would like to get the Component Metadata fields with a fieldBuilder.

I am successfully using the ['Plan B' code snippet in this post to access Component Fields](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/component-fields-available-in-gui-extension-with-fieldbuilder).  However, I cannot intuitively see a method in the APi to get the Metadata fields in the same manner.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fieldBuilder` you are accessing from that post is for the `SchemaBasedFields`.  I'm not sure if this is the official way of accessing the metadata `fieldBuilder`, but this is what I came up with playing around with it so far.

```js
var tabs = $display.getView().properties.controls.TabControl,
    cardCount = tabs.properties.cards.length,
    fieldBuilder,
    card;

while (cardCount--) {
    card = tabs.properties.cards[cardCount];
    if (card.getId() === "MetadataTab") {
        fieldBuilder = card.properties.controls.fieldBuilder;
    }
}
```

Now you have a `fieldBuilder` that represents your metadata fields, and would do the same as you would for the normal fields to grab the control.

```js
fieldsContainer = fieldBuilder.properties.input;
fieldsNode = fieldsContainer.getElement();

$j(fieldsNode).children().each(function (index, elm) {
    var cntrl = $j('div.input', elm)[0].control;
    console.log('fieldname=' + cntrl.getFieldName());
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help.  Works perfectly.  Also updated the blog post with your code, http://yabolka.com/gui-extension-readonly-and-hidden-fields-in-tridion-2011-and-up/

Answer (score 1):

Hope that this helps you to access some metadata field from your component with a fieldBuilder:

```
$display.getView().getMetadataTab().properties.controls.fieldBuilder.getField("field_name");
```