# Adding customized functionality on the Translation job component

Tags: gui-extensions

I want to add check box "Select All" functionality on the Translation job component, please see below screen shot.

[image]

using "Select All" I can select all below publication list or deselect as well.

Is there any way we can achieve this using GUI Extension or any other way.

Please suggest!!

Comment: As per the solution implemented by me, I have done some modifications to the Tridion existing files which is related to Tridion Translation jobs and it is working fine for me.

What are the legal issues which we can face if we modify the Tridion provided ASPX page, is this could cause support voilation? or this fine until it impact some tridion functionality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As another option I would suggest the Tab Initialize Extenders.

To use it you should create a class (well.. in terms of JavaScript of course ), implement public initialize method there, and register it as a Tab Initialize Extender for Translation Job General Tab (you should aslo configure Extension editor configuration to make this extension accessible).

[Example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a2e0ce4c5cf8ba934ef)

When Tab Control will initialize the General Tab it will also check its tabInitializeExtensions, and if there are any it will call initialize method from it.

In this extension you can create an Input Checkbox HTML element and implement event listener which will react on this check-box events by checking/unchecking the checkboxes in list.

Comment: how to implement this/**
* TODO: 
*  1\ Create Input field and append it tab HTML //Any example to for this
*  2\ Attach event listeners to the created input element //Any example to for this
*/

Comment: 1\ Something like `var i = document.createElement("input"); i.type = "checkbox";` plus `$("#DetailsPanel").appendChild(i);` for more info see your tab markup

Comment: 2\ `$evt.addEventHandler(inputCheckBoxElement, "click", this.getDelegate(this._onCheckBoxClick));`

Comment: thanks...did we have sample configuration file which we can use to configure this UIBeardcore.Extension.Tab.Views.Tabs extension given in above example...do we need todisposeInterface for our attached event listner as well

Comment: I went with different approach....we can customize our existing aspx page accordingly and add the required javascript in provided javascript for that page. Its working for me and company...thanks all for your support

Comment: What need to be added in extension.config for adding the Tab Initialize Extender if we go for Tab Initialize Extender, please clarify below statement
"register it as a Tab Initialize Extender for Translation Job General Tab (you should aslo configure Extension editor configuration to make this extension accessible)."

Comment: From implementation example the line which registers extender `Tridion.Controls.Deck.registerInitializeExtender("GeneralTab", UIBeardcore.Extension.Tab.Views.Tabs.SelectAllCheckboxExtension);`

Comment: Ok That i have used, what would the configuration setup, I have added seperate question for this http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2069/extended-javascript-is-not-getting-loaded-for-tab-initalizer-extender

Comment: You also should have this implementation available in a context of the tab implementation which you are extending. The best way to add it is to extend resource group with your file. Good example you can find in Erik`s reply in neighbor post http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/component-fields-available-in-gui-extension-with-fieldbuilder/1856#1856

I`g suggest the Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Editor.Views.TranslationJob

Answer (score 2):

I would probably start by adding a button to the ribbon instead of modifying the Tridion Edit view with a checkbox.

Then, when clicking the button, you would need to be able to grab the checkboxes in the form with Javascript / jQuery.  This part could take anywhere from a few hours to days, depending on your luck with Selectors and skill with JavaScript.  This kind of code is very specific to the Edit window you have open in Tridion.

It is also possible that in a future version of Tridion the HTML could change and your extension would need to be updated.  I would suggest to compare the HTML from 2011 to 2013 for this view.  I am guessing it is not changing too much.  This would then give your extension a good 2-3 years, if not more, before there would be any risk of it needing to be updated.