# Extended javascript is not getting loaded for Tab Initalizer Extender

Tags: gui-extensions, translation-manager

I am trying to implement this tab initialize extender [Tab Initalizer Extender](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a2e0ce4c5cf8ba934ef), Question related to this I asked earlier was [Related Question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/adding-customized-functionality-on-the-translation-job-component)

Before this extension I was already having some gui extension running on server, I added Tab Initalizer Extender configuration to the same configuration, please see below:

```
<cfg:group name="Extensions.Tab.Views.Tabs.SelectAllCheckboxExtension" merge="always">
    <cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:file type="script">/client/commands/TranslationJobSelectAll/SelectAllCheckbox.js</cfg:file>                
    </cfg:fileset>
</cfg:group>    

<extensions>
        <ext:editorextensions>
            <ext:editorextension target="CME">
                <ext:extendedareas>
                        <ext:add>
                            <ext:extension assignid="selectallcheckbox" name="selectallcheckbox">
                                <ext:control/>
                                <ext:pagetype/>
                                <ext:renderinblock>false</ext:renderinblock>
                                <ext:dependencies>
                                    <cfg:dependency>Extensions.Tab.Views.Tabs.SelectAllCheckboxExtension</cfg:dependency>
                                </ext:dependencies>
                                <ext:apply>
                                    <ext:view name="TranslationJobView">  
                                        //Do I need to create a usercontrol over here, I just want to add my "Select All" Checkbox to   TranslationJobView View                         
                                    </ext:view>
                                </ext:apply>

                            </ext:extension>
                        </ext:add>
                </ext:extendedareas>
            </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:dataextenders/>
</extensions>
```

Any idea why my mapped javascript is not getting loaded as I can't get any alert from the javascript.

**Edit:**

```
<cfg:extensiongroup name="SelectAllExtensionGroup">
    <cfg:extension target="Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Editor">
        <cfg:insertafter>SelectAll</cfg:insertafter>
    </cfg:extension>
</cfg:extensiongroup>


<cfg:group name="SelectAll">
    <cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:file type="script">/TranslationJobSelectAll/SelectAllCheckbox.js</cfg:file>
    </cfg:fileset>
</cfg:group>

<resourceextensions>
      <resourceextension>SelectAllExtensionGroup</resourceextension>
</resourceextensions>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I would recomment to make your own extension to not mess up with
  the one you already have. It`s easy :) : Check-out the tutorial:
  [Extensibility | Creating Editor Extension](http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2013/04/editor-extension/)
- If you want to extend Translation managed you should use 
  `<ext:editorextension target="Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Editor">`
- "Extendable Areas" are not supported in TM views, unfortunately.
- The best way to add the js file to current implementation is to
  associate it with the one of existing groups. Good how-to example you
  can find in Eric's [reply in neighbor post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1856/206) I'd suggest the
  `Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Editor.Views.TranslationJob` group to
  be extended

Comment: thanks...sure I will go with separate extension....in point 2 you suggest to use <ext:editorextension target="Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Editor"> instead of <ext:editorextension target="CME"> right?....in point 4 can you please more clarify about "is to associate it with the one of existing groups" as Eric examples does not clears my doubt

Comment: +2 In point yes, if you want to extend an Editor, you should put the editor name into target attribute. Check your System.config to verify your TM editor name.

Comment: +4 check-out this video http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2013/04/dependencies
In simple all UI Resoures are organized in groups. If you want to add new functionality to existing functionality, you should create your resource group, and extend the existing one. to do so, you should:  create your `group` with JS file as a resource -> configure existing group extension via `extensiongroup` -> register this extension as a `resourceextension`;

Comment: Thanks..I have added sample configuration in my edit section...Is it ok? as currently I can't test it (Out of office now) ....suggest any changes if there? InsertAfter is not clear

Comment: Yes, the sample should be fine. `target` is the attribute which specifies the group **being** extended; `insertafter` attribute specifies a group to be inserted after the group being extended. I would also strongly recommend to have a groups names in an extension namespace. So instead of `SelectAll` group, you will have for instance `Extension.TranslationManager.UI.Editor.SelectAll`