# How do I only load a specific Javascript file when the current view is a ComponentView?

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I would like to be able to only load a JavaScript file when the current view is a ComponentView.

So something in the lines of:

```
<cfg:group name ="groupname" applyTo="ComponentView">
  <cfg:fileset>
    <cfg:file type="script">/javascriptfile.js</cfg:file>
  </cfg:fileset>
</cfg:group>
```

Is there something available like this?

I know that you can do this within JavaScript ($display.getView()getId() === "ComponentView") but then the file is already loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to extend associated View group. In case of ComponentView it is  `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Component`

See how to make groupextensions from Eric answer in similar post:

[Component Fields available in GUI Extension with fieldBuilder](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/component-fields-available-in-gui-extension-with-fieldbuilder/1856#1856)

Comment: Thanks! I had already looked into extensiongroups but I didn't add the resourceextensions. It is working now.