# GUI Extension | How to Customize views for GUI extension

Tags: 2013, gui-extensions

I am trying to enable my control for DashboardView and ComponentView. In DashboardView view I can enable the control on selection of component which is working fine BUT if i open the component in ComponentView the control is not getting enabled. 
If some have the solution?
Here is the code

```
Extensions.HW.prototype.isAvailable = function HW$isAvailable(selection, pipeline)
{
 var items = selection.getItems();
  var item = $models.getItem(selection.getItem(0));

if (items.length >= 1 &&  item.getItemType() == $const.ItemType.COMPONENT ) { 
    return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

Extensions.HW.prototype.isEnabled = function HW$isEnabled(selection, pipeline) {
    var items = selection.getItems();
     var item = $models.getItem(selection.getItem(0));
    if (items.length >= 1 && item.getItemType() == $const.ItemType.COMPONENT ) {        
            return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

I am using two views in configuration as

```
      <cfg:dependency>HelloWorldRibbon.Commands</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>

      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="DashboardView">
          <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar" />
            </ext:view>
         <ext:view name="ComponentView">
          <ext:control id="ItemToolbar" />

        </ext:view>

      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
```

Here is the screenshot on which control is disabled
[image]

I want to enable this control while component is opened.

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint in the JavaScript? Is it being loaded/executed?

Answer (score 9):

Your logic for `isEnabled` and `isAvailable` is triggered around the `selection` variable, and in your case checking to see if the item selected is a component and that the number of items selected is at least one.  This works in your DashboardView when you select a component because your selection now has a length of one, and the `item.getItemType()` is a component.

However in your `ComponentView`, you don't have anything selected. You'll want to adapt your logic here to remain the same for `DashboardView`, but to always show for `ComponentView`.

You can modify your check to do something like:

```
if ($display.getView().getId() === "ComponentView") {
    return true;
}
...
can be considered a DashboardView at this point, put your existing logic here from your example to check the selection variable
...
```

Hope that helps! You should now have your extension always showing in the Component View (assuming that's what was desired), and only enabled in Dashboard view if you have selected a component item.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help. I tried this but unfortunately it returning 'DashboardView' when i tried alert($display.getView().getId()); inside isEnable and isAvailable methods. When i open the component in new window it still alert DashboardView.

Comment: Interesting, my experiment with 2013 has this working as "ComponentView" when I open up the component view window.  I've tried both as a command and in the console window... try typing in `$display.getView().getId()` from your console in the component window?

An alternative that you can try as well is : `if ($display.getItem().getItemType() === $const.ItemType.COMPONENT) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks Alex for your suggestion.I have tried this as well and after that I have removed all checks and just returning true from the Available and executes methods but it is still disabled in ComponentView.

Comment: Is your javascript loaded in ComponentView? When Tridion can't find your Javascript functions he will show the button as disabled.

Comment: Yes, If i open or refresh my componentView page, The _IsAvailavle method is called. I can check it by alert($display.getView().getId()); method but it always displays "DashboardView" as a result in the alert box. I also followed this  link : http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/how-do-i-only-load-a-specific-javascript-file-when-the-current-view-is-a-compone but it did not work for me :(

Comment: 'DashboardView' message is displayed in the alertbox while refreshing or opening ComponentView only when Dashboard and Component view are open simultaneously in different tabs on same browser. If i close Dashboardview tab and refresh componentView tab no alertbox is displayed. Does It mean javascript is not laoded for componentview?